# My first project EJB 3.0 / JSF 2.0 with Eclipse. How to test it?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to create my first project EJB3 with JSF 2.0 & Eclipse.
My first project is roughly a Hello World Project. I have an EJB interface, a bean that implements the methods and JSF ManagedBean with relative file .xhtml.
My problem is that I can not test the project. All files listed above are under the folder ejbModule, in a package, with the exception of the file. Xhtml which is in the META-INF folder. How can I test it? 
I am sure that this configuration is not correct. How can I integrate the two projects EJB and JSF. I have to create them separately and then link them?

```
package it.test.disco.core;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface MusicService {
  public String getDisco();

}
```

Class that implements interface:

```
package it.test.disco.core;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
  * Session Bean implementation class MusicServiceBean
 */ 
@Stateless
public class MusicServiceBean implements MusicService {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public MusicServiceBean() {}

public String getDisco(){
    return "The Knife DISCO DEL MESE";
}
```

}

Managed Bean JSF 2.0

```
package it.test.disco.core;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class DiscoStamp {
@EJB
private MusicService musicService;

public DiscoStamp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getMessage() {
    return musicService.getDisco();
}
```

and the file .xhtml

```
 <h:outputLabel value="NEWS DEL GIORNO: "/>
 <h:outputText value="#{DiscoStamp.message}"/>
```

Comment: Put them in the same EAR in order to be deployed together. For testing purposes, you can use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You need to Create One Enterprice Application using any IDE like netbeans/EClipse
where you can add Your XTML page to pages folder or JSp folder inside WEB-INF.

you can have source Folder where you can add ur EJB classess as well Action/ManagedBean.

And then You can have configure face configuration xml file and also web.xml and then you can use build your ear,

and now you can test/check your first code.